# Cannot get deeper to arrays and objects

Tags: json, reactjs, api

I'm looking for some explanation why in the `componentDidMount()` function, api returns all values ​​from API, but not in the `render()` function. In the render function I can only get to the first level as in the case of `{this.state.home.title}` but `{this.state.home.acf.hero_text [1] .text}` returns an undefined error.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import '../styles/App.scss';

class Home extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      home: []
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    let homeUrl = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/wp-json/better-rest-endpoints/v1/page/strona-glowna");
    fetch(homeUrl)
    let json = await homeUrl.json();
     this.setState({
       home: json
     })
     console.log(this.state.home);
     console.log(this.state.home.acf.hero_tekst[1].tekst); // works fine !
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.home.acf); // works fine !
    return (
      <div className="Home">
        Home
        <br/>
        {this.state.home.title} // works fine !
        {this.state.home.acf.hero_tekst[1].tekst} // trows an error: Cannot read property 'hero_tekst' of undefined
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried to use instead `useState`, `useEffect`, but the problem is the same. My guess is that the `render()` function is called before and that's why there is a problem, but how to make the API data go to the `render()` function.

Comment: Hi Negant, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

render function calls before the componentDidMount so the value of 
 {this.state.home.acf.hero_tekst[1].tekst} is undefined you have to write the check like

```
{this.state.home.acf.hero_tekst && this.state.home.acf.hero_tekst[1].tekst }
```

Comment: Works well, thank you!
I just had to change to:
`{this.state.home.acf && this.state.home.acf.hero_tekst[1].tekst}`

Answer (score 1):

`componentDidMount` executes after initial render. Initially, you state is empty.

So first time your component renders, it won't get any data and throws error. Then your `componentDidMount` executes which set's state value, here you can see updated state.

You should check if data is present,

```
{this.state.home && this.state.home.title} 
{this.state.home.acf.hero_tekst && this.state.home.acf.hero_tekst[1].tekst}
```